GenieBuilder Failed to make login request
I am getting started with GenieBuilder, I am following the tutorial Genie Create Web App
After installing GenieBuilder in Visual Studio Code, I run "Start GenieBuilder"

Everything seems to run Ok, until the end when I get the error:

Error: 2024-09-23 15:08:13 Failed to make login request: HTTP.Exceptions.ConnectError("https://genielicensing.hosting.genieframework.com/api/v1/login", CapturedException(OpenSSL.OpenSSLError("self signed certificate in certificate chain") ...

Does anyone knows how to fix it?
